# Как получить значение счётчика id (auto_increment) из базы данных?

Tags: java, embedded, база-данных

Возможно ли получить текущее значение счётчика id (auto_increment) - одна из колонок в таблице базы данных.

1. Используется **JDBC**
2. БД на всякий случай H2 (embedded)
3. Язык программирования Java

Интересует именно значение счётчика (оно отображает реальное количество добавленных записей в базу данных), а не id последней записи. Так как в момент получения данных несколько последних записей могут быть удалены.

Есть ли подобная функция в JDBC?

Как вариант конечно могу сохранять это значение в другую таблицу каждый раз при добавлении записи, но хочу надеяться, что есть способ красивее :).

Также нашёл метод getGeneratedKeys(), но опять же насколько я понял - он может вернуть значение ID только если прямо перед этим был выполнен INSERT в базу данных, что мне не подходит.

--
P.S. не хватает метки JDBC.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Непосрдественно к JDBC этот вопрос отношения не имеет. Нет какого-то стандартного "счетчика".

> Интересует именно значение счётчика (оно отображает реальное количество добавленных записей в базу данных), а не id последней записи. Так как в момент получения данных несколько последних записей могут быть удалены.

Непонятно, зачем это нужно. Если речь идет об оптимизации и быстром получении информации о кол-ве добавленных записей, то создайте специальную таблицу для хранения таких значений, а на вставку записей в исходную таблицу повесьте триггер, который будет инкрементировать счетчик при каждом добавлении записи.

Comment: Мне важно получить решение в виде функции на JDBC или в виде прямого запроса к БД.

Счётчик - это поле с auto_increment в базе данных. Я об этом писал.

Зачем нужно? Значение поля auto_increment обязательно где-то должно храниться(иначе как оно будет задаваться для следующей записи?), и, соответственно, если у пользователя есть доступ к данному значению - то намного проще сразу получить его, чем дублировать запись посредством создания новой записи в новой таблице. Как раз из-за оптимизации и быстрого получение информации и задан вопрос.

Comment: Нигде ничего не должно обязательно храниться. Еще раз, нет **стандартного** понятия - счетчик. Автоинкриментные поля в общем случае нужны не для счетчиков, а для генерации уникальных значений. 
Например в Oracle для этого есть последовательности (вроде как в H2 тоже). Значение из последовательности может инкрементироваться например на значение 50, и последовательность может представлять собой какой-то выделенный блок идентификаторов и любое обращение к этой последовательности может изменять значение вашего как бы счетчика.

Comment: В Microsoft SQL Server почему-то нет этих проблем. Там с помощью специальных и значение счётчика можно получить, и шаг. Если Вы привыкли пользоваться менее удобными СУБД, это не повод кидать понты вместо ответа на вопрос.

Comment: Речь идет не о понтах, а о специфике различных СУБД. Сомневаюсь, что IDENT_CURRENT в MS SQL дает т.н. значение счетчика. Хотя в некоторых случаях это будет его эквивалент.

Аналогом IDENT_CURRENT в H2 будет что-то вроде select TABLE_NAME.nextval from dual

Но, что я пытаюсь втолковать, это не счетчик. Это последовательность (sequence), что в общем случае вашу проблему не решит. В вашем конкретном варианте, может и поможет.

Answer (score 2):

В SQL Server есть функция IDENT_CURRENT('TableName'). Рекомендую поискать что-нибудь похожее.

Comment: Да, мне как раз нужен аналог данной функции. К сожалению найти пока не получается.

Comment: Могу порекомендовать только выделить себе период времени, который Вы можете потратить на поиск внятного решения. Если не найдёте - придётся делать костыль. Хотя, если Вы разрабатываете фреймворк, это не прокатит, и искать придётся до упора. Но, к сожалению, я не знаю СУБД H2 и не могу Вам подсказать.

Answer (score 1):

У меня тож такая задача была. И сколько я не изучал разные мануалы, статьи и хэлпы по БД, я не нашел такой функции. Т.е. вроде, можно и брать максимальный ID сразу после вставки, но тут могут возникнуть проблемы, и этот способ не подходит.
Я остановился на таком методе (хоть он и не сильно хорош по производительности):
          В моем случае было так, что если я делаю одну новую вставку в таблицу, то она уже уникальна (т.е. пять столбцов, и хотя бы один обязательно будет уникальным), т.е. если потом сделать выборку по условиям только-что вставленных значений, то это и будет именно та запись, которая была вставлена.

Но вот Вы указали,  что язык программирования Java. И вот в Java есть некоторые замечательные (хоть и сложные из-за большой своей функциональности) фрэймворки, которые полностью на себя берут взаимодействие с базой данных. А именно до той степени, что БД остается ТОЛЬКО хранилищем информации, и все. А бизнес-логика самой программы уже берет на себя ответственность за генерацию уникального ID, вставку, выборку и т.д. Вот два одних из самых известных: `EJB JPA`, и еще `Spring`. Такой подход находят хорошим многие программисты. 
          Мне видится еще один выход:
**Как** я понял, то, что Вы написали

> Интересует именно значение счётчика (оно отображает реальное количество добавленных записей в базу данных), а не id последней записи.

дак это то, что БД ставит уникальный ID в зависимости от количества уже присутствующих в БД записей. Ну, если это так, то :
Так как добавление новой записи в таблицу занимает очень мало времени, то ради хорошей и качественной функциональности программы можно и сделать так:

1. Когда ставится новая запись в БД, делать запрещение любых транзакций с таблицей (или со связанными таблицами, если это важно), кроме чтения;
2. Пытаться ставить новую запись: 
   **1** - вычислить количество записей,
    **2**-вставить запись с id=количество записей+1;
   **3**-сохранить этот ID для дальнейших нужд;
3. При любой ошибке и при любом завершении транзакции, делать дальнейшее разрешение изменений в таблице.

Не могу сказать сейчас откуда я этот способ прочитал, но была книга "умной".

Answer (score 1):

Итак... Подвожу итоги.

Наиболее правильный способ - это создать отдельную таблицу, куда и сохранять значение каждый раз при добавлении новой записи.

Менее правильный способ, но главное действующий. Основной смысл - получаем из служебной таблицы данное значение. Он подходит только для базы данных H2, но я уверен и в других база есть нечто подобное:

`//dbTable - название Вашей таблицы в БД
//ID - название столбца с auto_increment
//sequence_name - идентификатор строки со значением id (auto_increment)
//current_value - как раз искомое значение`

`SELECT sequence_name FROM information_schema.columns
WHERE table_schema = 'PUBLIC'
AND table_name = 'dbTable'
AND column_name = 'ID';`

`SELECT current_value FROM information_schema.SEQUENCES
WHERE sequence_name = 'sequence_name';`

Всем спасибо за помощь и отзывы!

Comment: Вы можете создать уровень абстракции от СУБД и в H2 обращаться к системной таблице (только запрос я бы порекомендовал переписать через Join), а в СУБД, поддерживающих функцию IDENT_CURRENT, вызывать её.

Answer (score 0):

У вас в вопросе полный каламбур (выражатся нужно точнее):

- "интересует значение счетчика" - неправильная постановка задачи;
- "оно отображает реальное количество добавленных записей в базу данных". тут сразу 2 неверных утверждения.

Я знаком только с ораклом, но кажется эти 2 варианта доступны и в других СУБД:

1. `select max(column)+1 from table_name;`
2. триггер, который при вставке будет заполнять автоинкрементное поле записи значением взятым из (1) или из другой таблицы.

update:

Стоит заметить, что в реальной БД, с которой я работал было такое решение:
процедура `get_next_id`, которая принимает след аргументы: имя таблицы, количество ид. И возвращала курсор с необходимым количеством ИД (процедура, т.к. для некоторых таблиц нужно было генерировать ИД, следуя некоторым правилам). Чтоб адаптировать под ваши нужды, можно добавить параметр column. Код примерно такой: а) `select count(*) from sequences where table_name = 'a' and column_name='b';` если ничего нет? тогда вставляем значение (1). Дальше инкрементим значение и возвращаем.